# Please explain this JavaScript logic

Tags: javascript

```
var isLogin = '';
if ('true' == 'true') {
   isLogin = '&is_login=true';
}
```

Came across this piece of JavaScript on a website. Can anyone explain why the author chose to set the value of `isLogin` this way?? As far as i can understand `('true' == 'true')` will always return `true`, so why not just initialize with the desired value?

Comment: programmer error?

Comment: He might want to explain you something else, you can just post that full content.

Comment: I think it's the result of a compiled source code (maybe use some kind of transpiler). In the real source code, maybe having 2 constants of 'true' values, and the if statement tried to compare these two.

Comment: This is definitely an error, just because `true` is defined as string and compared to another true string.. soo `'true' == 'true'` -> `true` -> `if(true)` -> useless